# Can we update Excel sheet by multiple threads at the same time using ExcelDataReader

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm need to read and update the Excel sheet at run time in my automation framework. 
For that i'm planning to use ExcelDataReader because it doesn't need any external dependency(like Oledb),

But here I'm using multi threading, i need to read and write the excel sheet by multi threads at the same time in same excel sheet.

How can i achieve this in ExcelDataReader????

Thanks in advance!
Elango

Comment: How are you going to get consistent results if multiple threads are doing reads / writes ?!

Comment: That (https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) looks like an implementation of `IDataReader`.  Readers read; they don't write.

Comment: @auburg We can get correct results each threads will read specified test data from data table and do testing and write into excel sheet by using update query by specifying column and row numbers, I have done in Oledb but it needs to MS access plugin installation,. That's why i'm looking alternatives....